# Refactor HABTM with checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many, form-helpers

i wanna refactor this code:

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag "contact[group_ids][]", nil %>
  <% Group.all.each do |g| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "contact[group_ids][]", g.id, @contact.group_ids.include?(g.id)%>
      <%= label_tag g.name %><br>
  <% end %>
```

I want use the form methods for this, example, but using check_box:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:departament_ids, Departament.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true}) %>
```

Or other way, but i guess very confuse use `hidden_field_tag` for edits in case of blank options and `@contact.group_ids.include?(g.id)` for options was choosed.

Any help? Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using rails 4 you can use [collection_check_boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

It will work the same way as collection_select so

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:departament_ids, Departament.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: In out of date versions exist other ways?

Comment: @user3251174 no, that's rails 4 only.  Rails 3 is either the current method you have or implement you own helper that works the same as collection_check_boxes does.